# HBASE - Increment and Increment Column Value are unable to increase counters in a distributed setup

Tags: hbase

I am using increment api of HBASE to increment counters in Hbase table, given the system is a distributed setup, multiple threads are trying to increment the counter at the same time and I am seeing that counters are not getting incremented to the value they should be. 
I am using HBASE version 0.94. Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Comment: I’m wondering too if this HBase Counter is working fine and was really implemented. However locking a HBase Cells is probably not a good idea at all for a distributed  database.
So I would go for another approach for counting like adding a new column with a UUID for each increment (works as far as your counters do no reach millions)

Comment: Please share a code sample which can reproduce it.